# Redirect All Subdomains from old domain to new one

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to move my site from:

```
old-domain.tld/anyfolder/anyfiles.ext
```

or

```
www.old-domain.tld/anyfolder/anyfiles.ext
```

to

```
www.new-domain.tld/anyfolder/anyfiles.ext
```

Permanently 301, and what's NC? Should I use one?

Any solution would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the htaccess file in your old-domain's document root, simply have:

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.new-domain.tld/
```

Or, if both domains share the same document root, you need to use mod_rewrite and check the HOST header:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?old-domain\.tld$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.new-domain.tld%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Since the HOST header can be upper or lower case, we use the `[NC]` (No Case) flag so that we match against it without checking case.